# lasso plugin selecting elements outside of the dragged area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using this [lasso plugin](http://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/511c5b658c405ad68941) to create lasso effect for my scatter plot. I changed name of the "d" attribute to "ls" as my scatter plot depends on d attribute to draw the symbols.  I got most functionality working but when I create a lasso area after dragging the mouse the elements outside of that lasso area also gets selected. Can someone please help me to figure out how to change the dragmove() function inside lasso.js so that only elements inside the loop gets selected. Here is my working code [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DyKAwJ2uWuyw7SACwKeT?p=preview) link. Thank you for your help.

```
function dragstart() {
            // Reset blank lasso path
            path="";
            dyn_path.attr("d",null);
            close_path.attr("d",null);
            // Set path length start
            path_length_start = 0;
            var offset_box = _this[0][0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

[image]

Comment: We need to see at least some of your code, preferably a working example to help you.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to add the link to my code. I edited my question or see the code at this link http://plnkr.co/edit/DyKAwJ2uWuyw7SACwKeT?p=preview

Comment: I ended up using point inside polygon js if it helps anyone.